# How to properly add a char* to a linked list without seg fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to add values (character arrays of file paths) to a linked list. I keep getting a Seg fault from my _add function and im not sure how to fix it. I've tried many different ways of writing the function but I've gotten nowhere. The answer seems simple I just can't get it. Here is my code for the _add function:

```
    typedef struct cplist {
        char *path; 
        int cpid;
        time_t  tv_sec;   
        suseconds_t tv_usec;
        struct cplist *next;
    } cplist;

cplist *cpl_add(cplist *head, char *path){
    cplist *current = head;
    while(current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = (cplist*) malloc(sizeof(cplist));
    current->next->path = path;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}
```

And here is my code from the main program. I'm reading in an optional '-v' flag, then an integer, then the paths that must be added to the linked list:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i, j;
    char *p;
    char *key;
    cplist *head = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-v") == 0){
            key = argv[2];
            for(j = 3; j < argc; j++){
                p = argv[j];
                cpl_add(head, p);
            }
        } else {
            key = argv[1];
            for(j = 2; j < argc; j++){
                p = argv[j];
                cpl_add(head, p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: `sizeof(head)` is the **size of the head pointer**, not the size of the structure. You should use `sizeof(cplist)`.

Comment: You're right. I'll make sure to edit that

Answer (score 0):

When you call `cpl_add(head, p)` you're actually calling `cpl_head(NULL, p)` .

Then you call `NULL->next` which blows up.

- Initialize `head` with `malloc` before adding to the tree.
- Be *sure* to set the linked list pointers in this element to `NULL`.

Other things you can do:

- Get rid of the useless `p` variable, just call it with `cpl_add(head, argv[j])` directly to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you once I initialized the head with malloc instead of NULL that fixed the seg fault

Comment: Don't forget to step through your code in a debugger if you ever hit a wall like this. If you pay close attention to the state of your variables you can usually spot problems like this.

Comment: @JoshPokorny It is a very bad idea to initialize the head node by malloc. All nodes should be created by the function. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function in general is incorrect because it does not process the list when initially the passed pointer to head is equal to NULL.

And you should make a copy of the passed string.

And moreover the function has return type that differs from `void` but returns nothing.

Apart from this it has a bug in this statement

```
current->next = (cplist*) malloc(sizeof(head));
```

You are not allocating a memory for a node. You are allocating a memory for a pointer. It is not the same.

The function can look the following way.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

int cpl_add( cplist **head, const char *path )
{
    cplist *current = malloc( sizeof( cplist ) );

    int success =  current != NULL;

    success = success && ( current->path = malloc( strlen( path ) + 1 ) );

    if ( !success )
    {
        free( current );
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy( current->path, path );
        current->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = current;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And call the function for example like

```
cpl_add( &head, argv[j] );
```